# Logic Error in closing SWF in a tab and can't open new html with ExternalInterface AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm facing a logic error here when i want to close tab in firefox through ExternalInterface, strangely nothing goes wrong in my output and compiler ,

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.system.fscommand;
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

letsPlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, loadIntro);

function loadIntro(e:MouseEvent){
    sndStart.play();
    sndmChannel.stop();
    //System.exit(0);
    fscommand("quit");
    ExternalInterface.call("window.open","http://localhost/GAME_FLASH/stage1/stage1story.html","_blank");
    ExternalInterface.call("closeWindow");
}
```

Firefox won't close the tab and won't the desired html in new window, i've checked everything including my html page. All the "import flash.bla bla" is complete nothing goes wrong there.

Comment: What's your JS code for 'closeWindow'?

Comment: @Kevin McGowan  it's contained with :

window.close()

Comment: Does the tab you try to close has been opened by a script (using window.open) ? If not, Firefox will simply refuse to close the window. It is a security feature that is implemented at least by Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @Aralicia Errr no, the tab is not opened by a script , i just normally open a new tab and open my flash html and when i click the "letsPlay" symbol to open new URL and close the current tab, the ExternalInterface.call seems not working at all.

Comment: If the tab isn't opened by a script; then you can't close it with a script. As I said, it's a security feature on most browser. What you try to do is sadly not possible.

Comment: @Aralicia Thanks for keeping up with me, i really aprreciate your help, now i know that there's a limit in executing it, i'll use a script to open it, my question is already answered by you, once again i say, Thank you :) you've ended my misery for these 3 days